# why dropdown select option dont working in some mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have a simple select tag in my project but in some mobile devices options don't appear, but in most of the devices its work well I tested some things and it's my code :

user-agent with the problem is : Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; SM-T285) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">dep</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <select class="form-control" name="depot_to">
        <option>choose dep ..</option>

           .
           .
           .
           .

    </select>
</div>
```

then I test with adding `data-native-menu="false"` like :

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">dep</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <select class="form-control" name="depot_to" data-native-menu="false">
        <option>choose dep ..</option>

           .
           .
           .
           .

    </select>
</div>
```

and then I added `<div class="ui-field-contain">` like :

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="ui-field-contain">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">dep</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select class="form-control" name="depot_to"
                data-native-menu="false">
            <option>choose dep ..</option>

               .
               .
               .
               .

        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I test it with simple without class like :

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">dep</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <select name="depot_to">
        <option>choose dep ..</option>

           .
           .
           .
           .

    </select>
</div>
```

but it's still don't work in my specific device 
can anyone help me?

Comment: Provide a proper [mre], give examples of what mobile devices and browsers show the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not fully sure what you meant don't appear. If you meant the options of select tag, it shows you only one option as you have specified only choose dep.. with option tag. The rest, I mean dots, wont display because they are not inside  tag.

If you want them to be displayed too, then you should wrap them with option tag.

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">dep</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <select class="form-control" name="depot_to">
        <option>choose dep ..</option>
        <option>option 1</option>
        <option>option 2</option>
        <option>option 3</option>
        <option>option 4</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

[image]

I hope it helps!